# Split up an iterable into batches

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

I was writing a program that had a list of e-mail messages. It needed to group them into batches, with the condition that each batch must have at max 20 messages, and be maximally 50k in size (no individual message is bigger than 50k). Obviously `itertools.groupby()` is a candidate for this, but I really didn't want to keep around a `key` variable, so I decided to write my own batcher:

```
def batch(iterable, condition_func=(lambda x:True), max_in_batch=None):
    def Generator():
        nonlocal n, iterable, condition_func, max_in_batch
        num_in_batch = 1
        yield n
        while True:
            n = next(iterable)
            if num_in_batch == max_in_batch or condition_func(n):
                return
            num_in_batch += 1
            yield n

    n = next(iterable)
    while True:
        yield Generator()
```

Sample run:

```
>>> gen = batch(itertools.count(1),(lambda x:x%10==9),7)
>>> list(next(gen))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> list(next(gen))
[8]
>>> list(next(gen))
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> list(next(gen))
[16, 17, 18]
>>> list(next(gen))
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
>>> list(next(gen))
[26, 27, 28]
```

What do you think? Is this Pythonic?

Comment: Did you consider something based on the `grouper` [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger thanks for pointing that out, though I don't think it's easy to modify that recipe to bring in the second condition.

Comment: Looks like the `iter()` built-in function is also close to what  Iwas wanting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Bugs

```
>>> gen = batch(range(50), lambda x:x%10==9, 7)
>>> for i in gen:
    print(list(i))


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#149>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in gen:
  File "<pyshell#142>", line 13, in batch
    n = next(iterable)
TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

Damn, I expected to be able to use iterables as the `iterable` parameter, not iterators.

Let's fix it:

```
def batch(iterable, condition_func=(lambda x:True), max_in_batch=None):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    def Generator():
        nonlocal n, iterator, condition_func, max_in_batch
        num_in_batch = 1
        yield n
        while True:
            n = next(iterator)
            if num_in_batch == max_in_batch or condition_func(n):
                return
            num_in_batch += 1
            yield n

    n = next(iterator)
    while True:
        yield Generator()
```

and try again:

```
>>> gen = batch(range(50), lambda x:x%10==9, 7)
>>> for i in gen:
    print(list(i))


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[26, 27, 28]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[36, 37, 38]
[39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
[46, 47, 48]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
[49]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#157>", line 2, in <module>
    print(list(i))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\idlelib\PyShell.py", line 1336, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Dang… Let's try to limit that:

```
def batch(iterable, condition_func=(lambda x:True), max_in_batch=None):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    def Generator():
        nonlocal n, on_going, iterator, condition_func, max_in_batch
        num_in_batch = 1
        yield n
        on_going = False
        while True:
            n = next(iterator)
            on_going = True
            if num_in_batch == max_in_batch or condition_func(n):
                return
            num_in_batch += 1
            yield n

    n = next(iterator)
    on_going = True
    while on_going:
        yield Generator()
```

Way better!

## Use a for loop to iterate over an iterator

Iterating over elements and maintaining a counter of how much elements were iterated over is usually done using a `for` loop combined with `enumerate`:

```
def Generator():
    nonlocal n, on_going, iterator, condition_func, max_in_batch
    yield n
    on_going = False
    # Start enumerate at 1 because we already yielded n
    for num_in_batch, item in enumerate(iterator, 1):
        on_going = True
        n = item
        if num_in_batch == max_in_batch or condition_func(n):
            break
        yield item
```

Using this construct also help handling the `on_going` flag (I don't like the way we *have to* change it twice to continue iterating): when the `break` is not reached, we know we have exhausted the iterator.

```
def Generator():
    nonlocal n, on_going, iterator, condition_func, max_in_batch
    yield n
    # Start enumerate at 1 because we already yielded n
    for num_in_batch, item in enumerate(iterator, 1):
        n = item
        if num_in_batch == max_in_batch or condition_func(n):
            break
        yield item
    else:
        on_going = False
```

## Use closures instead of `nonlocal`s

Specifying `iterator`, `condition_func`, and `max_in_batch` in the `nonlocal` clause is not necessary as they are not modified within `Generator`. Instead you should use standard scope resolution to do the job.

In fact, your use of `nonlocal` to get non-trivial side effects on `n` had me wondered if an inner function is really the way to go. Let's try OOP instead:

```
class Batch:
    def __init__(self, iterable, condition=(lambda x:True), limit=None):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.condition = condition
        self.limit = limit
        try:
            self.current = next(self.iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.on_going = False
        else:
            self.on_going = True

    def group(self):
        yield self.current
        # start enumerate at 1 because we already yielded the last saved item
        for num, item in enumerate(self.iterator, 1):
            self.current = item
            if num == self.limit or self.condition(item):
                break
            yield item
        else:
            self.on_going = False

    def __iter__(self):
        while self.on_going:
            yield self.group()
```

A bit more verbose but it seems to be a bit more explicit too. You use it as you would for your `batch` function:

```
>>> gen = Batch(range(50), lambda x:x%10==9, 7)
>>> for i in gen:
    print(list(i))


[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18]
[19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]
[26, 27, 28]
[29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
[36, 37, 38]
[39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]
[46, 47, 48]
[49]
```

Comment: Amazing! Yay! Thanks! BTW, why do you use the `break`-`else` combination in the last `group()` instead of just using `return`?

Comment: @Snowbody Both have the same effect. I just feel `break` is cleaner. If you don't, just use `return` without `else`.

Answer (score 1):

Yielding a nested `Generator()` is pretty weird.  Couldn't you just yield a list instead?

Taking some design cues from `itertools`, namely `takewhile()` and `groupby()`, I suggest the following more generic solution:

```
def groupwhile(pred, seq):
    """Generate lists of elements taken from seq.  Each list will contain
       at least one item, and will also include subsequent items as long as
       pred(group) evaluates to True for the proposed group."""
    seq = iter(seq)
    try:
        group = [next(seq)]
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    else:
        for item in seq:
            if pred(group + [item]):
                group.append(item)
            else:
                yield group
                group = [item]
        yield group
```

In this sample usage, `lambda group: len(group) <= 5 and sum(group) <= 50` quite clearly states what kind of group you are looking for.

```
>>> gen = groupwhile(lambda group: len(group) <= 5 and sum(group) <= 50, itertools.count(1))
>>> for batch in gen:
...     print('sum {} = {}'.format(batch, sum(batch)))
...
sum [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = 15
sum [6, 7, 8, 9, 10] = 40
sum [11, 12, 13, 14] = 50
sum [15, 16, 17] = 48
sum [18, 19] = 37
sum [20, 21] = 41
sum [22, 23] = 45
sum [24, 25] = 49
sum [26] = 26
sum [27] = 27
sum [28] = 28
sum [29] = 29
sum [30] = 30
sum [31] = 31
sum [32] = 32
sum [33] = 33
sum [34] = 34
sum [35] = 35
sum [36] = 36
sum [37] = 37
sum [38] = 38
sum [39] = 39
sum [40] = 40
sum [41] = 41
sum [42] = 42
sum [43] = 43
sum [44] = 44
sum [45] = 45
sum [46] = 46
sum [47] = 47
sum [48] = 48
sum [49] = 49
sum [50] = 50
sum [51] = 51
…
```

Comment: I know right? But it's what `itertools.group_by()` does. It doesn't ever make a copy; it points into the same thing the original iterator did. Though, mine makes a copy too, just of one item in each group. I'm not thrilled with your suggestion of doing all that copying so as to have real lists. Hmm. I'll have to think about this some more.

Comment: I do like your idea of having the list length be just another condition. I'm not sure why my initial idea was for the condition to be on the individual item as opposed to the whole group.

Comment: I don't think that there is much point in laziness when you've already encountered the items.

Comment: Note that by yielding generators, you are counting on the client being well-behaved, and emptying the generators in order. That is error-prone.